# How to import a contract with lower Solidity version?

Tags: solidity, remix

I want to import a deployed smart contract `TetherToken` and use its functions.

Solidity version of deployed contract `TetherToken` is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
...
```

I want to use its functions in my own contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.1;
import "TetherToken.sol";
contract L {
    address payable TetherAddress = 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7;
    TetherToken Tether = TetherToken(TetherAddress);
    ...
}
```

But `Remix` says:

> TetherToken.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different
> compiler version (current compiler is
> 0.6.7+commit.b8d736ae.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version pragma
> solidity ^0.4.17; ^----------------------^

It's important for me to use features of `Solidty 0.6.x`, and `TetherToken` also cannot be compiled by newer version of Solidity.

How can I solve the problem?

P.N: Can I use `ABI Code` of `TetherToken` instead of its source?

Comment: You don't need to import it, just declare `contract TetherToken {...}` and include inside it **the declaration** of whatever functions you're planning to call.

Comment: @goodvibration , Do you mean that no data is needed in used contract and only method interfaces is enough? What about modifiers and events?

Comment: The contract is already deployed at `0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7`, right? So all the implementation details are already "there" (on the blockchain). If you extend your question to show exactly which `TetherToken` functions you are calling, then I might be able to guide you with more specific details on what exactly you need to add in your code.

Comment: I use only `transfer()` function from `TetherToken`, But as I know the functions are not saved in the blockchain by their names alphabetically, so how can my contract can access the function by its name?

Comment: Doesn't matter, the compiler will translate your `TetherToken.transfer` function-call to the bytecode required for making this function-call execute correctly. But in order for the compiler to do that, it first wants to know the **prototype** of this function (i.e., its name, input argument types and return-value type). So you need to declare that prototype, but you don't need to implement the actual function.